# Can I send requests to another PC?

Tags: networking, server

My situation:

I have one internet connection thus one home account.
On my LAN there are a few PC's, a console and a server.

My provider's router is setup that requests from outside go to my server's IP.
My server is working as intended.

My problem:

When a connection on a certain port is made from the internet, I want the connection to go to another PC so I guess my server need to sent it to the other PC? I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu? We aren't necessarily networking experts here.

Comment: Do you mean port forwarding?

Comment: If you want to forward different WAN ports to different IP addresses on the LAN, that's something you would normally do directly on your router. Unless you are asking specifically about setting your server up as a gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing here, but the server is using ubuntu.

```
apt-get install rinetd
```

Given that you Ubuntu server has the ip 1.2.3.4, the other PC have the ip 1.2.3.5 and you would like to forward the port 8000. you need to change the `/etc/rinetd.conf` file.

```
# bindadress    bindport  connectaddress  connectport
1.2.3.4 8000  1.2.3.5 8000
```

Comment: Cheche, thanks alot. That is exactely what i need when i look to the manual. I didnt try yet but that will work im sure.